# How to concatenate selector in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, concatenation

I'm having trouble with a concatenation of a selector in `jQuery`. I have a dynamically generated form for creating estimates with 5 item lines. I need to calculate **Total Cost** by multiplying **Item Cost** and **Item Quantity**.  I have the following code:

```
NumberOfLinesInForm  = 5; 
var id;

for (i = 0; i < NumberOfLinesInForm; i++) {

    document.write(i);

    $('#ItemCost' + 'id', '#ItemQuantity' + 'id').keyup(function () {
        var ItemQuantityItem + 'id' = parseFloat($('#ItemQuantity' + 'id').val()) || 0;
        var ItemCostItem + 'id' = parseFloat($('#ItemCost' + 'id').val()) || 0;

        $('#ItemCostTotal' + 'id').val(ItemQuantityItem * ItemCostItem);

    });

}
```

I am trying to achieve this result in my `jQuery`:

```
$('#ItemCost1', '#ItemQuantity1').keyup(function () {

    var ItemQuantityItem1 = parseFloat($('#ItemQuantity1').val()) || 0;
    var ItemCostItem1 = parseFloat($('#ItemCost1').val()) || 0;

    $('#ItemCostTotal1').val(ItemQuantityItem1 * ItemCostItem1);

});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What happens with your code? Do you get any error? I don't get what you want to do.

Comment: Can you create a snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write the selector in the single string, so instead of:

```
$('#ItemCost1', '#ItemQuantity1').keyup(function(){
```

you use this:

```
$('#ItemCost1, #ItemQuantity1').keyup(function(){
```

When you use it like that, using two paremeters, the second parameter is used to denote the context, so `#ItemQuantity1` would never get selected: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

---

Next, if you want to concat variables, they **must not** be a string, so this:

```
$('#ItemCost' + 'id', '#ItemQuantity' + 'id').keyup(function(){
```

should be:

```
$('#ItemCost' + id + ', #ItemQuantity' + id).keyup(function(){
```

---

Next, this won't work:

```
var ItemQuantityItem + 'id' = ...
```

You're defining a variable, then adding a string to it and assigning all that a value.

Comment: Yup, just be more careful with strings and variables.

Comment: Is there any reason why this should not work: `var ItemQuantityItem0  = parseFloat($('#ItemQuantityItem' + i ).val()) || 0;` When I add `+ i` this code doesn't work anymore. If I just simply use `#ItemQuantityItem0` then it works. Is my syntax correct? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. Hmm, the syntax you provided looks good (it's different than the last paragraph in my answer, which won't work), could it be that the element with that id doesn't exist? What errors you see in the console?